# Jquery collapse and expand server side control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

i am using asp.net 3.5 and c#.

I have a server-side div (runat="server") and , what I want is this that when I click on the link, div1 will collapse. I have to do this in JQuery.

I already achieve the target to use the following example. It collapse and expand the client side div.. now i want to do the same thing to the server-side div control

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/animatedcollapse.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the problem? The only difference is that you need to use control's ClientID value. In your case if div with **jason** id has runat="server" attribute you may use: `animatedcollapse.addDiv('<%= jason.ClientID %>', 'fade=1,height=80px')`

Answer (score 0):

By 'do the same on the serverside', do you mean you want state to persist when you click on other elements that cause postback?

I did a blog post on doing this with a Panel control and remembering its state on the server side so if you click on other elements the state persists through postbacks.   It should equally apply to a DIV:
[Persisting Collapse state on postback](http://www.jonalb.com/post/2011/04/07/Upgrading-from-the-AjaxControlToolkit-Collapsible-Panel-using-jQuery-in-AspNet-WebForms-Remembering-the-Panel-State-across-postbacks.aspx)